# unable to sudo in docker image creation

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-16.04, sudo

I am trying to create a docker image from *Ubuntu 16.04 to run some python stuff. In the script I create a user with following command:

```
userad --create-home --gid sudo --shell /bin/bash testUser;\
echo 'testUser:superSecret007' | chpasswd;
```

This works fine. Next, I try to use this newly minted user account:

```
USER testUser
WORKDIR /home/testUser
```

Then when it this this line:

```
RUN sudo apt-get install -y libxml2;\
sudo pip install -r /home/testUser/requirements.txt;
```

It fails with following error:

```
Error : sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Note that `pip` is installed before creating user and also following runs successfully:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip;
```

Comment: Why do you do these things after installing the user? You were root just a moment ago; do these things before dropping your privileges.

Comment: @tripleee I'll look at other question. And yes your second point is valid as well. But knowing how to overcome this is a good thing in itself.